# Will N'Zoth the corrupter re-summon an Unearthed Raptor?

Tags: hearthstone

The scenario is pretty simple. Say I copy the deathrattle of a "Fiery Bat" onto my raptor. **If my raptor dies, will N'Zoth the Corrupter re-summon it?**

I understand that N'Zoth will not re-summon minions that have been "given" a deathrattle. But does the raptor's ability really count as "giving" itself a deathrattle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, N'Zoth will not re-summon Unearthed Raptor. It isn't a Deathrattle minion, it's a Battlecry minion. Once it's dead, it no longer has the Deathrattle attached.

[Blizzard confirmation](https://twitter.com/playhearthstone/status/713054676564975620)

Comment: Awww... I was really hoping to make use of this interaction in my Raptor Rogue deck... guess it just wasnt meant to be